# Read host in powershell not working correctly

Tags: powershell

I just can't get the read host yes/no prompt to work properly.

```
do { $answer = Read-Host "yes or no" } 
until ("yes","no" -ccontains $answer)

if ($answer = "$yes"){
   write-host "time is enabled"
} Else {
   write-host "time service disabled"
}
```

It always jumps to else, sorry I'm kinda new.

cheers

Comment: You have left a $. Try if ($answer = "yes")

Answer (score 4):

Common syntax error - don't use `=` where you mean `-eq` :)

`if ($answer -eq "yes"){`

Answer (score 0):

The code you supplied is contains a typo, **-ccontains** should be **-contains**

Also, the line: **($answer = "$yes")** is comparing the $answer variable to the $yes variable, which does not exist in the snippet you provided.

If you're trying to see if the $answer variable is equal to "yes", then remove the dollar sign from the beginning of the string.

Here is the corrected version:

```
do { $answer = Read-Host "Yes or no" } 
until ("yes","no" -contains $answer)

if ($answer -eq "yes")
{
   write-host "time is enabled"
}
else
{
   write-host "time service disabled"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue is with the line `if ($answer = "$yes")`.

- First, [as Stephen pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25990026/2495), `=` always means assignment in PowerShell. To compare the values, you would use the `-eq` operator.
- Second, the comparison value `"$yes"` is also inadvertently using [variable expansion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/07/15/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-herestrings.aspx). Since the variable `$yes` is not defined, the operand evaluates to the empty string, `""`.
- The end result is that `$answer` is overwritten with `""`, which is then evaluated by the `if` statement as being [logically false](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx), thus entering the `else` block.

Changing the line to `if( $answer -eq 'yes' )` will fix the issue.

---

Also, the use of the case-sensitive `-ccontains` operator in the `do`/`until` loop is more restrictive than it needs to be. The default in PowerShell is to do case-insensitive comparisons, so that entering `yes`, or `Yes`, or `YES` will all pass.

Alternatively, if case-sensitivity is important for your scenario, you might want to consistently use case-sensitive operators throughout your script (i.e. using `-ceq` in your `if` statement).

For more information, see the help topic [`about_Comparison_Operators`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113217).